# Text overlapping using table in IEEE conference template

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicolumn, multirow

Good afternoon.

Before asking the the question I really worked flat out in order to just understand the reason of text overlapping in my example but it was unsuccessful.

Having looked some solutions devoted to "text overlapping" I transformed the code a bit but it did not help. The reason of that is most probably that my understanding of *multicolumn*, *multirow* and table building in LaTex does not mean a thing.

What I am trying to get is table (red polygon is not necessary):
[image]

My LaTex code for that:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
  \setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|P{0.1\linewidth}|P{0.1\linewidth}|P{0.1\linewidth}|P{0.2\linewidth}|P{0.2\linewidth}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{CASE}                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{CONTROL REQ'T}              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{WHAT IS ACHIEVED}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{RATING INCREASE}                                                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{INCREASED RATING OF...}                                                        \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Capacitive de-energizing}   & \multirow{4}{*}{Opening at optimum arcing time} & \multirow{4}{*}{Increased voltage withstand} & Increase of voltage rating                                                                  & 1 step (e.g. 145 to 170 kV)                                                                        \\
\cline{4-5}
                                            &                                                 &                                              & Higher rated frequency                                                                      & 50 to 60                                                                                           \\
\cline{4-5}
                                            &                                                 &                                              & Lower ambient temperature class                                                             & Lower ambient temperatures can be met (e.g. $-40^{\circ}C$ to $-50^{\circ}C$) on same type of CB   \\
\cline{4-5}
                                            &                                                 &                                              & Higher capacitive switching class                                                           & Class C1 breaker can become class C2 breaker free of charge (except the cost for controller)       \\
\hline
Filter bank switching                       & Opening at optimum arcing time                  & Increased voltage withstand                  & TRV withstand                                                                               & Additional application of standard CB                                                              \\
\hline
Line energising                             & Optimum closing and re-closing                  & Reduced transients                           & With the combined use of line arresters and controllers ßmaller" breakers can be used       & 1-2 voltage step(s) up-rating (300 kV CB to be used for 420 kV)                                    \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Fault current interruption} & \multirow{2}{*}{Opening at optimum $T_{arc}$ }  & \multirow{2}{*}{Increased $I_{SC}$ }         & Increased current breaking (possible increased break time depending on speed of algorithms) & Approx. 10\%20\% depending on type of fault condition                                              \\
\cline{4-5}
                                            &                                                 &                                              & Lower ambient temperature class                                                             & Lower ambient temperatures can be met (e.g. $-40^{\circ}C$ to $-50^{\circ}C$) on same type of CB   \\
\hline
Missing current zero                        & Opening at optimum (delayed) time               & Ability to interrupt highly offset currents  & Current interruption                                                                        & Successful interruption instead of unsuccessful                                                    \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The code gives (it is seen that table overlaps second column of a paper):

[image]

Please can someone just tell me:

- **What is going on?**
- **Where did I commit a faux pas?**
- **What the best, the elegant and the fast way to get the table of need?**

[IEEE Template LaTex just in case](https:///www.ieee.org/conferences/publishing/templates.html)

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want your table to be as wide as one column  or as wide as both columns?

Comment: The former. That is to be as wide as one column.

Comment: Do you want the contents of the cells to be horizontally centerd of left aligned? Your definition and use of the `P` type columns makes me think, you want then centered, your first image however shows left aligned text. Please clarify.

Comment: Having had a closer look at your table I highly doubt it will fit well into a single column while keeping a readable font size. Probably it would be better to allow it to span both columns to improve the readability by avoiding too many hyphenations.

Comment: Entirely unrelated to the question, but please consider using `siunitx` and `\SI{-40}{\degreecelsius}` instead of `$-50^{\circ}C$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two versions of your table. As you can see, I had to reduce the font size very drastically to somehow squeeze the table into a single column. You hopefully agree that the version that spans both columns looks considerably better:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text. Do not use in real document.

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{P}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[htbp]
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|P{0.125\linewidth}|
                 P{0.15\linewidth}|
                 P{0.125\linewidth}|
                 0{P{0.3\linewidth}}|
                 0{P{0.3\linewidth}}|}
\hline
\thead{CASE}                  
  & \thead{CONTROL\\ REQ'T}              
    & \thead{WHAT IS\\ ACHIEVED}        
      & \thead{RATING INCREASE}                                                       
        & \thead{INCREASED RATING OF...}                                                        \\
\hline
\multirow[t]{10}{=}{Capacitive de-energizing}   
  & \multirow[t]{10}{=}{Opening at optimum arcing time} 
    & \multirow[t]{10}{=}{Increased voltage withstand} 
      & Increase of voltage rating                                                                  
        & 1 step (e.g. 145 to 170 kV)                                                                        \\
\cline{4-5}
  &
    & 
      & Higher rated frequency                                                                      
        & 50 to 60                                                                                           \\
\cline{4-5}
  & 
    & 
      & Lower ambient temperature class                                                             
        & Lower ambient temperatures can be met (e.g. \SI{-40}{\degreeCelsius} to \SI{-50}{\degreeCelsius}) on same type of CB   \\
\cline{4-5}
  &
    &                                              
      & Higher capacitive switching class                                                           
        & Class C1 breaker can become class C2 breaker free of charge (except the cost for controller)       \\
\hline
Filter bank switching                       
  & Opening at optimum arcing time                  
    & Increased voltage withstand                  
      & TRV withstand                                                                               
        & Additional application of standard CB                                                              \\
\hline
Line energising                             
  & Optimum closing and re-closing                  
    & Reduced transients                           
      & With the combined use of line arresters and controllers ßmaller" breakers can be used       
        & 1-2 voltage step(s) up-rating (\SI{300}{\kilo\volt} CB to be used for \SI{420}{\kilo\volt})                                    \\
\hline
Fault current interruption
  & Opening at optimum $T_{arc}$   
    & Increased $I_{SC}$         
      & Increased current breaking (possible increased break time depending on speed of algorithms) 
        & Approx. 10\%20\% depending on type of fault condition                                              \\
\cline{4-5}
                                            
  &                                                 
    &                                              
      & Lower ambient temperature class                                                             
        & Lower ambient temperatures can be met (e.g. \SI{-40}{\degreeCelsius} to \SI{-50}{\degreeCelsius}) on same type of CB   \\
\hline
Missing current zero                        
  & Opening at optimum (delayed) time               
    & Ability to interrupt highly offset currents  
      & Current interruption                                                                        
        & Successful interruption instead of unsuccessful                                                    \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\lipsum \lipsum



\begin{table}[htbp]
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\hspace{0pt}\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}}
\centering
\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\tiny}
\begin{tabular}{|P{0.175\linewidth}|
                 P{0.2\linewidth}|
                 P{0.2\linewidth}|
                 0{P{0.225\linewidth}}|
                 0{P{0.2\linewidth}}|}
\hline
\thead{CASE}                  
  & \thead{CONTROL\\ REQ'T}              
    & \thead{WHAT\\ IS\\ ACHIEVED}        
      & \thead{RATING\\ INCREASE}                                                       
        & \thead{INCREASED\\ RATING\\ OF...}                                                        \\
\hline
\multirow[t]{10}{=}{\hspace{0pt}Capacitive de-energizing}   
  & \multirow[t]{10}{=}{Opening at optimum arcing time} 
    & \multirow[t]{10}{=}{Increased voltage withstand} 
      & Increase of voltage rating                                                                  
        & 1 step (e.g. 145 to 170 kV)                                                                        \\
\cline{4-5}
  &
    & 
      & Higher rated frequency                                                                      
        & 50 to 60                                                                                           \\
\cline{4-5}
  & 
    & 
      & Lower ambient temperature class                                                             
        & Lower ambient temperatures can be met (e.g. \SI{-40}{\degreeCelsius} to \SI{-50}{\degreeCelsius}) on same type of CB   \\
\cline{4-5}
  &
    &                                              
      & Higher capacitive switching class                                                           
        & Class C1 breaker can become class C2 breaker free of charge (except the cost for controller)       \\
\hline
Filter bank switching                       
  & Opening at optimum arcing time                  
    & Increased voltage withstand                  
      & TRV withstand                                                                               
        & Additional application of standard CB                                                              \\
\hline
Line energising                             
  & Optimum closing and re-closing                  
    & Reduced transients                           
      & With the combined use of line arresters and controllers ßmaller" breakers can be used       
        & 1-2 voltage step(s) up-rating (\SI{300}{\kilo\volt} CB to be used for \SI{420}{\kilo\volt})                                    \\
\hline
Fault current interruption
  & Opening at optimum $T_{arc}$   
    & Increased $I_{SC}$         
      & Increased current breaking (possible increased break time depending on speed of algorithms) 
        & Approx. 10\%20\% depending on type of fault condition                                              \\
\cline{4-5}
                                            
  &                                                 
    &                                              
      & Lower ambient temperature class                                                             
        & Lower ambient temperatures can be met (e.g. \SI{-40}{\degreeCelsius} to \SI{-50}{\degreeCelsius}) on same type of CB   \\
\hline
Missing current zero                        
  & Opening at optimum (delayed) time               
    & Ability to interrupt highly offset currents  
      & Current interruption                                                                        
        & Successful interruption instead of unsuccessful                                                    \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: the `\linewidth` could be added to the `\newcolumntype` command if desired